# Truncate data when viewed digitally; Include all data when exported

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I wrote a formula to truncate my Crystal Report's data with a * if the data happens to be longer than 8 characters. For example, `123456789` becomes `*23456789`

Now I need to somehow keep the original data when exported. So Crystal Report Viewer should truncate to 8 characters, but on export the full data should display regardless of size.

It seems the only way to do this is to use an extra export button and parameter to toggle the truncate behavior - unfortunately this is not possible. How else can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: Just to be clear, you mean to say you can't add the extra parameter? Or you can't add an extra button?

Comment: cant add the extra button. According to my research that seems to be the only way to discover if the report is "exporting"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a format formula called display.

Right click on the data and then format object on the first page you'll see "display string".

Use your formula there to edit the display of the data.

Note that this will edit the display for the report in the crystal reports viewer, pdf exports, and the non data excel exports.

CSV and data only excel exports will be exported with the full data.

Answer (score 1):

Your question boils down to "*Can a Crystal Report detect whether or not it's being exported?*" - which as far as I know, it can't do.

That said, you could achieve the same effect by adding an extra parameter. In your case all you would need is a Boolean, let's call it `Truncate`. Then use `Truncate` to determine whether or not your formula runs. Turn it off when you want to export, turn it on when you just want to view.

```
If {?Truncate} = 0 Then 
    // Your formula here
Else 
    // Unformulated field
```

You shouldn't need to use a completely separate button if you went this route. Just add `Truncate` alongside the other parameters.

Comment: I found a format formula for "Display". Using my formula on that worked to show the * number while exporting data only formats i.e. (csv, excel data only) would then show the full number. Thanks for the tip!